# List Coordinates of Pixels Inside a Triangle

Tags: c#, math, xna

I'm making a game in C# and XNA, and I was trying to come up with a method to render massive terrains without using a tremendous amount of memory or passing the poly limit hard-coded into XNA.

My solution so far is to create a massive heightmap, and that heightmap is loaded into memory at the beginning of the game in the initialization phase. Then, terrain is only generated nearest to the camera. This is accomplished by projecting a triangle whose vertex is the character and the other two endpoints extend to the sides of the character's viewing area. Then, all the pixels inside that triangle on the heightmap are rendered and drawn into the game, thus only rendering what is seen.

The problem is, I've successfully found (I think, can't test until I get terrain rendering) the three vertices of the triangle. Now I need to find a list of the coordinates for every single pixel inside that triangle - whole numbers only, because I just need a list of pixels to render.

I know it sounds a little confusing, so here's the gist of it:

I have an image, and I project a triangle onto that image. The only thing I know about that triangle are the three vertices. I need a list of the pixels inside that triangle.

I've been Googling around for maybe 20 minutes now, and I figured I midas well go ahead and post something here due to the fact that what I'm trying to do isn't all that common. If I find an answer, I'll be sure to post it here.

But until then, can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

**Edit:** A formula, please. If you can provide a formula or algorithm, and an explanation, that would be just perfect.

**Edit:** I've posted a new question, as I've ditched this method of rendering large terrains. The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124695/efficient-method-of-rendering-massive-terrain-in-xna).

Comment: I certainly don't want to dissuade you from experimenting and having fun but the maths for calculating when a point (or a collection there of) is within a camera frustrum might prove to be faster / easier (not least of which because the existing infrastructure can help out).
If you're truly interested in high performance rendering of large terrains, you might want to invest some time looking into topics such as instancing and billboarding.

Comment: @lzcd Yeah, I'm open to pretty much anything right now. I'll take a look and research into instancing and billboarding and see if I have any chance at making them work.

Comment: Because the player can presumably turn rapidly, you'll have to send all the height data in the view frustum each frame - which will chew up a fair bit of bandwidth. I imagine you'd be better off breaking your terrain into chunks, loading the nearest chunks to the player onto the GPU, and then streaming in new chunks in the background, as the player moves. How big is your heightmap? How much do you expect to be visible to a player (with a 360° view) at once?

Comment: @Andrew The perspective Matrix is 45 degrees. As for distance, the user should be able to view 512 pixels away on the heightmap, which translates to ~2500 scaled up by 5 in-game.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand how big your heightmap is, or the visible region. Can you describe it in terms of an absolute number of polygons?

Comment: The actual heightmap I'm using to test is 4096x4096 pixels in size - saved as a 4-bit bitmap (to conserve space, might make it 8-bit if I notice a loss of quality). Optimally, I'd like to render 1024x1024 slots of terrain at a time, but I'm afraid that would surpass XNA limits on polygons in primitives. I've decided that if I render a 512x512 section, I end up with 262144 squares, and multiplying that by 2, I get ~500k polygons.

Basically, the user would see 256 pixels of the heightmap in front of him, but I scaled that by 5, so they actually see 1280 in front. I'd like it to be bigger though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start here:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleInterior.html

One of the non-trivial problems, not mentioned there, that you have to deal with is the pixelization along the boundary.